# Minimization of Maximum Eigenvalue Error for Richardson Extrapolation

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, problem-solving, fixed-point-iteration, chebyshev-function

I am asked to solve the following problem:

Consider k-steps of Richardson's method with different parameters $\omega_1, . . ., \omega_k $. The error equation is then: $$ e_k = (I - \omega_kA)...(I - \omega_1A)e_0 $$

Consider the optimization problem of choosing k-parameters:
$$ min_{\omega_i \in \Bbb R, i=1,...,k} \,\, [max_{\lambda \in[\lambda_{min}(A),\lambda_{max}(A)]} \,\,|(I-\omega_k\lambda)...(I-\omega_1\lambda)|\,] $$

Find the solution and derive the rate. This trick is known as the Chebyshev Acceleration.

Some things I know regarding the eigenvalues of the Richardson method:

$$ \lambda_{min}(A) \gt 0 $$
$$ 0 \lt \omega\lambda_{max}(A) \lt 2 $$
$$ \lambda_{min}(A) \le \lambda_{max}(A) $$
$$ 0 \lt \lambda_{min}(A) \le \lambda \le \lambda_{max}(A) $$

I also know the optimal value of $ \omega $ for the Richardson's method as:
$$ \omega^* = \frac{2}{\lambda_{max}(A) + \lambda_{min}(A)} $$

I am not sure how to proceed with this problem. I could look at the problem in the simplest form (k=2) that way I only have two terms. Could I treat $ \omega $ as essentially being constant in order to find the eigenvalue(s) which would lead to the highest absolute eigenvalue error? Then minimize the overall error with a choice of $ \omega $?